# DataGridView returns "Index out of range" when in separate class

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to access the data in a dataGridView in Form1. Even when I manually insert rows, when I search the item (0, 0), it returns the exception "Index out of range". So I tried a few things with no success.

To test, in the second class, I have the code:

```
MessageBox.Show(MyForm1.dataGridView1[0,0].ToString());
```

This didn't work, so I tried using get in the main class.

```
    public DataGridView data1
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1;
        }
    }
```

With this in the second class:

```
MessageBox.Show(MyForm1.data1[0,0].ToString());
```

Comment: Are you set `MyForm1` to Opened Form or it is just name of Form ?

Comment: It is not a good approach to access UI elements from other forms. It is a much better approach to share common data. That means you ceate a model for your data and share it beetween your forms.

Comment: are you sure the form is open when you execute that command?